# AngularJS some places $rootScope not working in safari browser

Tags: angularjs

In my code I wrote `ng-if="myrootScopevariable"` in html for hiding and showing one div and doing `$rootScope.myrootScopevariable = true;` in JS Controller it is working for **Google Chrome and Firefox** but **not in safari**.

Comment: It's good to provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng-if="$root.myrootScopevariable"
```

Comment: maybe ng-if="$rootScope.myrootScopevariable" will work for you. Can you provide jsfiddle?